# Pronoms interrogatifs

Tags: pronoms, questions, interrogative

Je sais que les expressions interogatives ci-dessous sont correctes :

> Qu'est-ce qui t'embête ?
>      Qu'est-ce qui t'a fait mal ?
>      Qu'est-ce que ça/cela veut dire ?
>      Qu'est-ce qui vous y attire ?

Je voudrais savoir si les expressions ci-dessous sont correctes ou non et pourquoi.

> Que veut dire ?
>      Qu'est-ce qui veut dire « apothéose » ?
>      Qu'y attire ?
>      Que se passe t-il ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only admissible one is “*Que se passe-t-il ?*” (note the addition of a hyphen between passe and t)

- “*Que veut dire ?*” is not correct (it is equivalent to “What means?”)

  The correct form would be “*Que veut dire… ?*” (“What does … mean?”)
- “*Qu'est-ce qui veut dire* apothéose *?*” is not correct either (“What does it mean *apothéose*?”)

  You should use “*Que veut dire* apothéose *?*”
- “*Qu'y attire ?*” → “What appeals to?”

  Try “*Qu'est-ce qui vous attire ?*” instead (“What appeals to you?”)

By the way, this is not correct: “*Qu'est-ce qui vous y attirez ?*”

It should be “*Qu'est-ce qui vous y **attire** ?”* (What appeals to you about it, what attracts you to it) because the subject of attire is *qui*, not *vous*.

Comment: Or *qu'est-ce que veut dire apothéose* ; as long as *qui* becomes *que* it works.

Comment: Que veut dire X? What does x mean? Qu'est-ce que apothéose veut dire? Like: Qu'est-ce que  cela veut dire? What does apotheosis mean? And: Qui est-ce que vous attirez? is a possibility. Whom do you attract?

Comment: @Lambie You forgot an elision: *Qu'est-ce qu'apothéose veut dire ?*. Nobody says *qui est-ce que vous ...?* because it sounds too much like *qu'est-ce que vous ...*. Idiomatic alternatives are: *Qui attirez-vous ?* (formal),  *Vous attirez qui ?* / *Qui c'est que vous attirez ?* (usual spoken French), and *C'est qui que vous attirez ?* (colloquial)